# Why the first function is not triggered in this way?

Tags: jquery

I tested this code snippet but the first function is not executing while the second one does.Why is this? The same function works fine on hover event..

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("p").mouseover(function(){
                $(".Stop").text($(".Stop").text()+"  Test 0");
            },function(){
                    $(".Stop").text($(".Stop").text()+"  Test 1");
                }

            );
    })
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.Stop{color:red;border:#000 thin solid;width:100px;}
</style>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form name="frm1" >
    <input type="text" id="myForm"/>
    <input type="text" id="myForm1"/>
    <input type="text" id="myForm2"/>
</form>
<p class="sakl" >Click</p>
<p class="Stop"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [`mouseover()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) does not take two function arguments. What do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nowhere in the [jQuery documentation for `mouseover`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) does it specify that two functions can be used with it. You'll have to use [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover) for this, which does much the same job.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p").hover(function() {
        $(".Stop").text($(".Stop").text() + "  Test 0");
    }, function() {
        $(".Stop").text($(".Stop").text() + "  Test 1");
    });
});
```

Comment: As the OP noted himself *"The same function works fine on hover event..."*

Comment: @Tomalak: Indeed. I don't see anything wrong with using `hover`. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

what is the behaviour you need, if you need something to happen when the mouse leaves the paragraph area use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("p").mouseover(function () {
        $(".Stop").text($(".Stop").text() + "  Test 0");
    } );

    $("p").mouseleave(function () {
        $(".Stop").text($(".Stop").text() + "  Test 1");
    }
 );
})
```